# Database migration: auto-incremented foreign key trouble

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, auto-increment

I'm trying to do a simple migration of some data from an old MySQL database to a new MySQL database. The data that I'm migrating is from a forum, so two tables: `threads` and `posts`. I was doing fine until I ran into some tricky auto-incremented foreign-key relationships.

**Database schema** (simplified to the important parts):

```
threads (id, title, user_id, created_at, updated_at)
posts (id, thread_id, user_id, body, created_at, updated_at)
```

As you can see, `thread_id` is a foreign key corresponding to the `id` of the thread the post belongs to. Here lies the problem: the new database already has threads and posts in it, and the primary keys are **auto-incremented**. It's not hard to see what the problem is: the thread and post ids in the two data sets won't match up/will conflict with each other! If I just filled in the posts table, they would now correspond to the wrong threads etc.

How can I resolve this, inserting the threads/posts from the old data set into the new data set without screwing up the `id`s and relationships? Ways I have thought:

- add a large number to the old thread/post ids so they won't conflict with the new ones
- give up and walk away with my tail between my legs, figuring it's not possible

Is there an easy way to do this that I'm missing? The "adding a large number" method doesn't seem ideal to me. Database wizards, please apply! **The solution will be where the old data is added to the new database, and all posts still belong to the correct threads.**

Comment: if the old database is consistent, then surely it will remain consistent when imported? an auto increment field is only calculated if not supplied or zero. Or do you have to merge the old database into a new one with clashing ids?

Comment: I have to merge the old database into the new one with clashing ids. That's the problem. i.e. there is a thread with `id` = 1 in the old database as well as the new one, but they are different and have different posts. Also there are missing numbers because threads have been deleted, so if I just put them in and allow auto-increment to work they still won't match I think? I could be wrong, this is making my brain hurt.

Comment: I'm also trying to preserve the right post->thread relationships. I.e. ensure that each thread still has the right posts belonging to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- find max thread id in new database MAX
- make a copy of the old database
- in your copy of the old database, `UPDATE threads SET id=id+MAX` and `UPDATE posts SET thread_id=thread_id+MAX`;
- import these remapped threads and posts into the new database - when you import the posts, use 0 for the id so that you do get a fresh post id though.

Comment: Yeah this is what I'm doing now.. the "add a large number greater than the max id in the new database" to the old database, then adding. We'll see what happens...

Comment: I was trying to explain same, but in very hard way :D .
@Paul, thanks for help

Comment: This is probably going to take me a few stumbles to get it fully right, but I agree this is the right/best process. Thank you.

Comment: For anyone who is also doing this, you have to remove the `auto_increment` when you bump the thread ids up by `MAX`.